# Join Table Values in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have an index() function on a controller that lists all of my users. Currently I can list all users, and values for the users but I can't get information from another table. Here is an an example of an SQL query I am trying to replicate in Eloquent.

> SELECT user.id, user.name, user.email, user.title, timezones.name FROM users, timezones WHERE user.timezone=timezones.id

The way in which I currently display the users is:

> $users = User::latest()->paginate(5);
> return view('users.index', compact('users'));

Table structure is as follows

Users Table:

> id | name | email | timezone (int)

Timezone Table:

> id | name

To output the data this is my index.blade.php file:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
<tr>
<td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->title }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->timezone }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to `join` the `timezones` table instead:

```
$users = User::select('user.id', 'user.name', 'user.email', 'user.title', 'timezones.name as timezone')
    ->join('timezones', 'user.timezone', 'timezones.id')
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: This helped solve my problem. The final solution was:

$users = User::select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.email', 'users.title', 'timezones.name AS timezone')
                        ->leftJoin('timezones', 'users.timezone', 'timezones.id')
                        ->orderBy('users.name', 'ASC')
                        ->paginate(5);

Comment: @BeatinCakes Glad I could help. The other option would have been to rename the `timezone` field in your `users` table to `timezone_id` and then create a `timezone()` `belongsTo` relationship in your `User` model.